# Get records from multiple Hive tables without join

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have 2 tables :

**Table1 desc:**

```
count int
```

**Table2 desc:**

```
count_val int
```

I get the fields count, count_val from the above tables and insert into the another Audit table(table3) .

**Table3 desc:**

```
count int
count_val int
```

I am trying to log the record count of these 2 tables into audit table for each job run.

Any of your suggestions are appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more explicit plz ? count and count_val are some fields of the tables or they are calculated values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just aggregations (like sums), the solution comes with the use of UNION

```
INSERT INTO TABLE audit 
    SELECT
        SUM(count),
        SUM(count_val)
    FROM (
            SELECT
                t1.count,
                0 as count_val
            FROM table1 t1 

            UNION ALL

            SELECT
                0 as count,
                t2.count_val
            FROM table2 t2
    ) unioned;
```

Otherwise join is required, because you should somehow match your lines, it's how relational algebra (the theory behind SQL) works.

```
==table1==
| count| 
|------|
|  12  |
|  751 |
|  167 |

===table2===
| count_val| 
|----------|
|   1991   |
|   321    |
|   489    |
|   7201   |
|   3906   |

===audit===
| count | count_val| 
|-------|----------|
|   ??? |    ???   |
```